# Staying up to date with TensorFlow Master from Source?

Tags: python, tensorflow, nvidia

So I have started to do some serious learning with TensorFlow 
My configuration is:
Ubuntu 16.04
Nvdia 1070 card with CUDA 8 and CUDNN 5.1
Anaconda for python
I have installed TensorFlow from master via source, which I gather is required to support the newer Nvidia drivers and Ubuntu 16.04. And things are now running but for instance I noticed a caution that TF master may have model saving broken at the moment so I will have to do something before too long..

TensorFlow is clearly evolving very quickly and the install process from source is time consuming and potentially error prone. (yeh I get that this is bleeding edge)

Any suggestions on how best to update on a regular basis (both the Nvidia, which I think is taken care of via the PPA, and the TensorFlow from GIT Master?) without a total wipe and reinstall Mainly focussed on TensorFlow ?

Suggestions appreciated!

Comment: You can sync on a regular basis and build PIP wheels (see tools/pip_package/build_pip_package.sh ). Then you can install each wheel in a new env, and switch back to an older env when new env didn't work

Comment: That may be ii, not a bad approach...